# In Node.js bcrypt.compare() always return false

Tags: node.js, encryption, bcrypt

when I put the correct password it returns false as it should return true

```
exports.login = async (req, res) => {
  const { body } = req;
  try {
    console.log("body", body);
    let user = await userService.getUserByEmail(body.username);
    console.log("Database User: ", user);
    //const password = await authHelper.encryptStringg(body.password);
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(HttpCodes.UNAUTHORIZED).json({ message: AppMessages.INVALID_USER_CREDENTIALS });
    }
    console.log("body.password", body.password)
    console.log("typeof(body.password)", typeof(body.password))
 

    const isValidPass = await authHelper.validatePassword(body.password, user.password);
    console.log("Encrypted user.Password :", user.password);
    console.log("Password Comparison Result:", isValidPass);
    if (isValidPass) { 
      return res.status(HttpCodes.OK).send("Login Successfully.");
    }
    return res.status(httpCodes.UNAUTHORIZED).json({ Message: AppMessages.INVALID_USER_CREDENTIALS });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
    return res.status(HttpCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).json({
      Error: AppMessages.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
    });
  }

};
```

I used the below method becrypt.compare to compare the hashed password and the plain

```
exports.validatePassword = async (requestedPassword, encryptedPassword) => {
  //const spass=await this.encryptStringg(requestedPassword);  
  console.log("spass: ",requestedPassword);
  console.log("enc pass:",encryptedPassword);
  try {
      let isValidPass = await bcrypt.compare(requestedPassword, encryptedPassword);

      return isValidPass;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error in validatePassword:", error.message);
      return isValidPass;
    }
  };
```

The output I got

```
Hello. Welcome to localhost 8080.
body { username: 'john1234@gmail.com', password: 'john1234' }
Database User:  {
id: 20,
username: 'john1234',
email: 'john1234@gmail.com',
password: '$2a$10$IanIACxB.uBfqJfAUNCkeuNzWg8qZ6PfS8G54Kmmj1L',
role: 'user'
}
body.password john1234
spass:  john1234
Encrypted user.Password : 
$2a$10$IanIACxB.uBfqJfAUNCkeuNzWg8qZ6PfS8G54Kmmj1L
```

Password Comparison Result: false

I expect that when I entered the correct credentials the bcrypt.compare() method

returns **true**

Comment: The only reasonable reason why it returns false is if there's something wrong with your inputs. It might help you share the output of your `console.log` statements. Also the catch statement will return `undefined` but I don't think that's the issue here. I think it's better not to catch.

Comment: Indeed those 2 don't match. The bcrypt hash was not for that password. It's probably a mistake during storing the password.

Comment: I double check the stored password and the entered password are the same.

Comment: I don't know what else to tell you. The hash you shared is *not* correct for 'john1234', so it would always be false. If you don't believe there's a bug in the code that generates the hash, I'm afraid I can't help you.

Comment: are you sure bcrypt was used to encrypt the password when it was created?

Comment: @GarrGodfrey it's almost certainly a bcrypt hash, given the '$2a$10$' prefix. The input string must have been something else

Comment: I think that hash is truncated. Is a bcrypt hash not supposed to be 3+3+1+53=60 characters? `encryptedPassword.length == 50` if the output in your post is accurately copy-pasted.

Comment: The first 22 characters after the third `$` are the salt, the remaining 31 are the actual hash, see [here](https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js#hash-info). You can reconstruct the complete value with `console.log(bcrypt.hashSync("john1234", "$2a$10$IanIACxB.uBfqJfAUNCkeu"))` which returns `$2a$10$IanIACxB.uBfqJfAUNCkeuNzWg8qZ6PfS8G54Kmmj1LDHLyvZ.pOS`

Comment: `console.log(bcrypt.compareSync("john1234", "$2a$10$IanIACxB.uBfqJfAUNCkeuNzWg8qZ6PfS8G54Kmmj1LDHLyvZ.pOS"))` returns `true` (as it should be). The generated value corresponds to your value, but in your value the last 10 characters are missing (`DHLyvZ.pOS`). Maybe this happens when saving in the DB. Note that I used the synchronous counterparts for simplicity.

Comment: Thanks to all @Topaco, RickN, Garr Godfrey, and Evert  The password stored in DB is truncated after hashed as I changed the password length in DB then it works.